# What website URL do I provide if I’m registering an API with an identity provider

Tags: .net, api, oauth-2.0, swagger-ui

I want to register my app with an Identity Provider so that I can use OAuth with Swagger UI.

However I’m not sure what website URL to provide since the app is just in development.

Thanks

Comment: Does your identity provider documentation provide any tips for which URL to use for in-development apps?